# Stream reader - individual line reading

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, stream, visual-studio-2017

I have a game that I want to save the player's settings into a file, that will be in the game's folder. I am using a stream reader, but I can only write the data to the file, I can't retrieve it. I want to be able to read any line I want from the file, because later I will want to make a if condicion for like: If line 12 is = 6, then: ...  But how do I specify a line from my file?

```
string txtFilePath3 = @".\dataconf3.txt";
            string[] data =
            {
                saveData.Default.Name,
                saveData.Default.Money.ToString(),
                saveData.Default.Level.ToString(),
                saveData.Default.firstTime.ToString()
            };

            StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(txtFilePath3);

                for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(data[i]);
                }

            sw.Close();

            StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(txtFilePath3);

            for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + sr.ReadLine();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try like:

```
richTextBox1.Text = File.ReadAllLines(txtFilePath3);
```

or if you want to parse line by line:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamRerader(txtFilePath3))
{
   while (!sr.EndOfStream)
  {
      var line = sr.ReadLine();
  }
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, but I manage to get another solution for it. But thanks for your help, that gave me a starting point to get to my solution!